# Reading binary image data from a web service into UIImage

Tags: iphone, web-services, binary-data

I'm consuming a web service in my iPhone app. The web service method returns a response which has several fields (eg. ID, Description, etc..). One of these fields contains binary image data which I need to convert to UIImage in my iPhone application.

I'm using a NSXMLParser successfully to extract data from the XML response. In the `parser:foundCharacters:` selector of the XMLParser, it gives a `NSString*` pointing to the string within each field. Since this is a string, this is what I do to read image data when i encounter the image field:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

But img variable is still "nil" after this line. Seems like the data from XML string is not compatible with conversion. What am I doing wrong here? (I'm capable of reading other fields into my variables but not this image data field)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following fbrereto's answer, I managed to convert the string into NSData using a code sample at this link: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour (scroll to the code sample by MiloBird user). Now I can construct the image successfully.

It uses objective-c categories to add the selector `+ (id)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;` to the NSData class. Here's the necessary code sample I extracted from the above link:

```
//MBBase64.h

@interface NSData (MBBase64)

+ (id)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;     //  Padding '=' characters are optional. Whitespace is ignored.

@end


//MBBase64.m

static const char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

@implementation NSData (MBBase64)

+ (id)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;
{
    if (string == nil)
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:nil];
    if ([string length] == 0)
        return [NSData data];

    static char *decodingTable = NULL;
    if (decodingTable == NULL)
    {
        decodingTable = malloc(256);
        if (decodingTable == NULL)
            return nil;
        memset(decodingTable, CHAR_MAX, 256);
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            decodingTable[(short)encodingTable[i]] = i;
    }

    const char *characters = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (characters == NULL)     //  Not an ASCII string!
        return nil;
    char *bytes = malloc((([string length] + 3) / 4) * 3);
    if (bytes == NULL)
        return nil;
    NSUInteger length = 0;

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (YES)
    {
        char buffer[4];
        short bufferLength;
        for (bufferLength = 0; bufferLength < 4; i++)
        {
            if (characters[i] == '\0')
                break;
            if (isspace(characters[i]) || characters[i] == '=')
                continue;
            buffer[bufferLength] = decodingTable[(short)characters[i]];
            if (buffer[bufferLength++] == CHAR_MAX)      //  Illegal character!
            {
                free(bytes);
                return nil;
            }
        }

        if (bufferLength == 0)
            break;
        if (bufferLength == 1)      //  At least two characters are needed to produce one byte!
        {
            free(bytes);
            return nil;
        }

        //  Decode the characters in the buffer to bytes.
        bytes[length++] = (buffer[0] << 2) | (buffer[1] >> 4);
        if (bufferLength > 2)
            bytes[length++] = (buffer[1] << 4) | (buffer[2] >> 2);
        if (bufferLength > 3)
            bytes[length++] = (buffer[2] << 6) | buffer[3];
    }

    realloc(bytes, length);
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:length];
}

@end
```

Thank you all!

Comment: I have the exact problem like you did. I am happy that I found your answer, but I don't really understand the code and how should i use it. I have a string currentElementValue that I parsed from a web service and I want to convert this into nsdata, so that i can convert further into image. Could you give me a few suggestions please? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's very late for this answer. But you can use the method provided in the example and call it like this:

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:currentElementValue];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

Answer (score 1):

The trick with `NSString` is that there is an implicit encoding associated with the data it contains. The image you are receiving, however, is likely in a format that will not convert properly, as it is either binary data or some lossless encoding of binary data (e.g., base64). The trick, then, is to make sure you don't let `NSString` perform any encoding conversions at all, otherwise your image data will be corrupted. Instead of using `dataUsingEncoding:` I would try an API more like [`getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:). While more complex than `dataUsingEncoding:` I think it'll give you the flexibility you need to get *just the data* from the NSString and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable idea, but then again, I would need to know the number of bytes in the string. How can I know that? both `[string length]` and `[string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding]` involves character encoding. If I can know the byte length, I might be able to use [string getCString] to get the raw bytes. Thanks again.