# Binary row data to image conversion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can I convert binary data to image ?
I have binary file which content of RGB 565 bitmap image. i want converted .bin file in to image.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: How u create that file?

Comment: Please have a look at this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360986/reading-binary-image-data-from-a-web-service-into-uiimage

Comment: in file content binary rgb 565 data.  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test_29" ofType:@"bin"];
  NSData *byteData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: This format is not supported.  I believe you have to convert it to RGBA8888 first, unless it is inside of a .BMP file

Comment: how to convert RGB 565 to RGBA8888 ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *retrieved = [UIImage imageWithData:
                          [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length]];
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the data, you have to first convert it to a native format of iOS (RGBA8888, ARGB8888 or RGB888).  [This method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/Reference/vImage_conversion/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vImageConvert_RGB565toARGB8888) should help you with that.  Now all you have to do is get the data inside of a `vBuffer`.  After you get the data out as RGBA8888, you need to make a `CGBitmapContext` with the data and get a `CGImage` out of that.  So, in the end, I suggest you switch formats if you can.  You won't save any performance by doing it this way.