# convert PIX object to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to apply a threshold using the leptonica image library with the function

```
l_int32 pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold()
```

I believe I have succesfully used this function but as you can see, it returns an int. I am not sure how to go from here and convert this into a UIImage OR convert the PIX object I passed in into an UIImage? Basically I just want a UIImage back after applying the threshold.

The API for this function can be found here: http://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/binarize_8c.html#aaef1d6ed54b87144b98c72f675ad7a4c

Does anyone know what I must do to get a UIImage back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another user converting data to image...
[Reading binary image data from a web service into UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360986/reading-binary-image-data-from-a-web-service-into-uiimage)

but if you can i would look into brad larsons awesome gpu image filters may be better suited for you https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage very easy to use

added answer for adding GPUImage framework: sorry i cant help with the first as for if you would like to continue using the second if you simply need a desired threshold effect you can use gpuimage as a frame work and after setup for adaptive threshold i simply used a switch case for different effects or call init how ever you want and i used a slider to get effects control or select a predetermined value but the code ends up as easy as this

```
 case GPUIMAGE_ADAPTIVETHRESHOLD:
    {
        self.title = @"Adaptive Threshold";
        self.filterSettingsSlider.hidden = NO;

        [self.filterSettingsSlider setMinimumValue:1.0];
        [self.filterSettingsSlider setMaximumValue:20.0];
        [self.filterSettingsSlider setValue:1.0];


        UIImage *newFilteredImage =  [[[GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter alloc] init] imageByFilteringImage:[self.originalImageView image] ];
        self.myEditedImageView = newFilteredImage;
    }; break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. For your first point, can you tell me how that would help me? The pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold() returns 0 for no errors and 1 for an error. Secondly, I have played around with Brad Larsons GPU image. It is great but I have not been able to get the desired effects like pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold(). Can you tell me which specific methods should be used? Thank you!

Comment: sorry i can't be more help with the threshold you want to use but theres some code added to my original answer if you want to play with GPUImage filter